# Mysqldump isn't working: "command not found"

Tags: mysql

I have to export a database from the command line. I tried using this command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name > backup.sql
```

But it returns this error:

> -bash: mysqldump: command not found

After this, I also tried with

```
sudo mysqldump
```

but the error is the same.

I'm at the beginning and I'm not very good at it at the moment. If I have to work on directory, please be clear because I'm not confident with the terminal.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: I'm working on OS X El Capitan.

Comment: First try to find where is mysqldump command `whereis mysqldump` OR try using `/usr/bin/mysqldump`

Comment: /usr/bin/mysqldump returns this error: " -bash: /usr/bin/mysqldump: No such file or directory"

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam
    whereis mysqldump
doesn't return anything.

    /usr/bin/mysqldump
returns this error:
    -bash: /usr/bin/mysqldump: No such file or directory

Comment: Does `mysql --version` work? I mean: Is MySQL installed after all?

Comment: @PerlDog
If I type that command, the error is always the same. But I can run MySQL.

Answer (score 9):

If you have the latest mysql installation in El Capitan, the mysqldump executable should be in the `/usr/local/mysql/bin` directory.
In order to use it, you can either run `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump` directly, create a symlink, or add the whole bin directory to your path, so you can use any of the executable files without typing the full path.

As suggested below, you can easily make a symlink in your `/usr/bin` directory, which should already be in your path, by running this command: `ln -s /usr/bin/mysqldump /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump`

That command should create a link called mysqldump in your `/usr/bin` directory, which will redirect to the full path of the mysqldump program.

If you would rather add the entire mysql library of tools, all at once, you can follow this guide: https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/add-shell-path-osx/ and learn how to add new directories to your path.

Comment: Creating a `.bash_profile` file would not affect any other users. Why not just make a symlink from `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump` to `/usr/bin`?

Comment: @Mike
As I said in the question, I'm not an expert in using the line command. Can you explain me how to make symlink? Thank you.

Comment: @Mike updated my answer to suggest creating a symlink

Comment: @Daniel
Excuse me, but I don't understand. I did what I had to do according to the guide in the link, but the error is always the same.
I type in the command line the following command:

'mysqldump -u root db_name > /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump/db_name.sql'

But it returns:

<-bash: /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump/db_name.sql: Not a directory>

Can you help me please?

Comment: ahh... try running this command `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root db_name > ~/db_name.sql` Does that make more sense? Hopefully you'll get a database dump in your home directory. :)

Comment: Well, it seems correct, but the prompt goes in the next line and it doesn't return anything...
Luckily I found the solution! Thanks to the guide in the Daniel's link and to this video 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2hsOk0XcYC4' I think I've solved the problem.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: Great! If you feel I answered the question, you can mark it as the accepted answer. :) Glad you got your database backed up!

Answer (score 7):

If you not installed MySql.
Ubuntu

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install mysql-client
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a semi-colon to the end of your command, it could make all the difference. I was getting the same error and that fixed it for me.

I'd also suggest declaring everything explicitly in the command you're running. The following worked for me:

1) Find the direct path to your `mysqldump` file. Check `usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump` if installed using MySQL Server DMG, or if you're using homebrew check in `usr/local/Cellar/mysql...` (even just do a spotlight search for it).

2) Create a folder to dump the backup to. I made mine `~/dumps`.

3) Tie it all together, ensuring you have a semi-colon at the end!

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p db_name > ~/dumps/db_name.sql ;
```

Comment: It should be noted, if you installed MySQL with homebrew your `mysqldump` may very well be in a different directory top that mentioned in my answer. Check `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.6/5.6.43/bin/mysqldump` or similar. Certainly look for mysql in `/usr/local/Cellar` and follow the white rabbit.